# Why was this particular post deleted?

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions

*[Java Incremental operator query (++i and i++)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24422298/java-incremental-operator-query-i-and-i/)* was the post link before being deleted.

I got the last image of that post from [Google cache](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:SwbdMJiqNzwJ:stackoverflow.com/questions/24422298/java-incremental-operator-query-i-and-i%20&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=bd).

This question received six votes, and my accepted answer received six votes. It was a year-old post. Suddenly I got an edit notification a little later and when I visited the link, the post was gone.

I have read the *[Why and how are some questions deleted?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-questions)* post, but I still don't get it.

Can anyone give me an exact explanation?

Comment: The post was closed as a duplicate, and 4 community members voted to delete the post. It could be that they felt the question wasn't a good sign-post (i.e. it doesn't help people find the canonical).

Comment: I've undeleted the post; I don't see any need for that post to remain deleted.

Comment: @MartijnPieters "It could be that they felt the question wasn't a good sign-post" that seems a good reason... and I don't see any important missing keyword that the targets don't have... the (previously deleted) question doesn't have any (weak title, not even many words outside the code blocks)

Comment: @MartijnPieters I just expected an explanation to understand, got undeleted as bonus :D . That's great man and thanks a lot.

Comment: @Braiam: but the *answers* are used by search engines too. There were good answers there, there was no crap here that had to be deleted.

Comment: @pnuts: the answers are too much tailored to that specific question to make sense on the other post.

Comment: @MartijnPieters that is a good sign that they are not duplicates, then. Reading the question the OP seems to have *two problems*, one, the addition operator after and before the variable (pass-by-value), and, two, the use of the functions. The duplicates only address the first issue.

Answer (score -7):

It is a duplicate post, and before you asked, it had already been discussed so it was closed, and for the same question users can refer to an earlier post of this same question.